# SQL doctrine query that has as many results as values ​passed in parameters

Tags: php, sql, symfony

Assume that I give to a function an array :

```
$arrValues = ['19', '4', '4', '18', '19']
```

To a function :

```
$objRequeteDoctrine = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('o')
    ->from('xxxxxx', 'o')
    ->where('o.id IN (:values)')
    ->andwhere('o.actif = 1')
    ->setParameter(':values', $arrValues );

return $objRequeteDoctrine->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Here, it'll retrieve 3 objects(duplicates removed). But what if I want to retrieve 5 objects, with duplicates ? Is that possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicates"? Usually, an SQL query does not return any duplicates

Comment: I mean that this query will return me an array of 3 objects xxxxx fromd ids 19,4 and 18. But is there a trick for retrieve an array of 5 objects, with ids 19,4,4,18,19 ?

Comment: If you want to achieve this, why not write some code for that?

Comment: Try to make some `UNION ALL` (one for each value of the array) maybe ?

Comment: depending on your database, there are sometimes things like virtual tables, with which you could join thus getting rows from the primary table multiple times. I would certainly not do it. I would just fill the array in php according to what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the answer to your question to achieve this with Doctrine but can be a solution to your problem. **What about generating the full array afterwards?**

```
$arrValues = ['19', '4', '4', '18', '19'];

$objRequeteDoctrine = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('o')
    ->from('xxxxxx', 'o')
    ->where('o.id IN (:values)')
    ->andwhere('o.actif = 1')
    ->setParameter(':values', $arrValues );

$result = $objRequeteDoctrine->getQuery()->getResult();

// Get the object ids in a separate array to find their position in the result

$idsOnly = [];
foreach($result as $entity) {
    $idsOnly[] = $entity->getId();
}

// Find the key of the object by id in the first result

$fullResult = [];
foreach ($arrValues as $id) {
    $keyFound = array_search($id, $idsOnly);
    if ($keyFound !== false) {
        $fullResult[] = $result[$keyFound];
    }
}

return $fullResult;
```